# ngStorage crashes in Chrome iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Chrome denies access to localStorage when run inside a cross domain iframe.
This causes ngStorage to crash the entire application

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/e8y85/

Stacktrace:

```
Error: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
    at Error (native)
    at Object. (https://rawgit.com/gsklee/ngStorage/master/ngStorage.js:42:41)
    at Object.d [as invoke] (https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js:28:304)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js:30:39
    at c (https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js:27:142)
    at d (https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js:27:276)
    at Object.instantiate (https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js:28:434)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js:53:326
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js:44:274
    at n (https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js:7:74)
```

As Dave already said this happens when blocking tracking cookies.
However forcing our users to accept tracking cookies is not an option

[image: Chrome Security Settings]

Is there any workaround in terms that it does not crash?
**Losing the stored data is not an issue.**

Default browser settings:
[image: Browser defaults]

Comment: The provided jsFiddle works perfectly fine in 38.0.2096.0 dev

Comment: I don't understand. You asked browser to block 3rd-party cookies and **site-data**, but you want to `access 3rd-party site-data`, which is localStorage.

Comment: The standard setting on all browsers (best of my knowledge) is to allow 3rd parties to store data. **If this setting is not allowed, no workaround exists.** You can look at cookies, JStorage, doesn't matter. The browsers will not allow any data saves. This is a lock-down mode.

Comment: @DaveA I am okay with not accessing it or losing session data - I just don't want that it crashs my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ngStorage` module you are using contains code to check whether local storage is *supported*:

```
var webStorage = $window[storageType] || ($log.warn('This browser does not support Web Storage!'), {})
```

However, as you've noticed this doesn't deal with the case where it's supported but yet *disabled*.

The easiest solution would be to modify `ngStorage` itself to handle this situation. For example:

```
var webStorage;
try {
    webStorage = $window[storageType] || ($log.warn('This browser does not support Web Storage!'), {});
}
catch (ex) {
    webStorage = {};
    $log.warn('Access to web storage is denied.')
}
```

There already seems to be [an issue open for this](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage/issues/57) with a similar code change attached to it.

Since `ngStorage` is crashing on instantiation of those services, you could also change your application to conditionally load `$localStorage` based on your own check, at the expense of some ugly, non-idiomatic code:

```
var localStorage;
try {
    localStorage = $window.localStorage;
}
catch (ex) {}

var $localStorage = localStorage ? $injector.get('$localStorage') : {};
```

This assumes that instead of requesting the `$localStorage` dependency in your controller you'd request `$window` and `$injector` and then instantiate `$localStorage` dynamically only after you've proven that it will work. If you access the local storage in many places in your application then you could factor out this into your own service. Pushing for the patch to be included in `ngStorage` is certainly cleaner, though.

Comment: Actually that looks like a nice work around  - the issue you mentioned was opened by me but it looks like ngStorage isn't well maintained.

Comment: Oh, heh. Sorry I didn't make the connection between your users on github and stackoverflow even though the names are the same. Sorry for being redundant.

Comment: Does the $log.warn show a message to the end user?  or does it depend on the injection?  (I can debug the .js file in IE, but not chrome, thus why I can't just point a breakpoint on it and follow it)  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

This jsFiddle works on my chrome browser (Version 36.0.1985.125 m).

Maybe you have corrupted Storage. Try to clear your ngStorage with [`$reset()`](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage) on the [plnkr.co website](http://plnkr.co/).

```
<button ng-click="$storage.$reset({
      x: 999
    })">Clear localStorage</button>
```

### [Like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/YiG28KTFdkeFXskolZqs?p=preview).

(Or with js : `localStorage.clear();`).